# Android and java JSON

Tags: java, android, json, graph, webview

I’m new to using JSON and am currently playing around with the FLOT graph to display a graph through WebView.

http://rapidandroid.org/wiki/Graphing

However, when it comes to JSON parsing I'm having trouble getting my data to represented as the JavaScript equivalent. I have been playing around with this for hours and I'm unable to get my JSON output to look like the following.

```
var datasets = {
    "Symptoms": {
        label: "Symptoms",
        data: [[1988, 10], [1989, 20], [1990, 10], [1991, 30], [1992, 40]]
    },        
    "Reactions": {
        label: "Reactions",
                    data: [[1988, 0], [1989, 0], [1990, 10], [1991, 30], [1992, 40]]

    },
    "Injections": {
        label: "Injections",
                    data: [[1988, 0], [1989, 0], [1990, 0], [1991, 30], [1992, 40]]

    },

};
```

Using davids interpretation of the flot graph 
http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-charts-the-html5-and-javascript-way/

Thanks in advance.

P.s. the closest I have gotten is:
String data= "[0,1],[5,3],[5,6],[7,2],[10,12]";
arr.put(data);

put the problem is the out is:
{"data":["[0,1],[5,3],[5,6],[7,2],[10,12]"]} //how can I get rid of .. " ..
also how am I able to get label: in the JSON object? also without quotation marks

---

**Solution**

To pass a json object from android to javascript (i.e. webview)
Good for anyone using the flot javascript library to display
a graph in android

Java Activity

```
String json = "{"
             + "  \"Symptoms\":"
             + "{  \"label\": \"Symptoms\","
             + "  \"data\": [[1988, 10], [1989, 20], [1990, 10], [1991, 30], [1992, 40]] "
             + "},"
             + "  \"Infections\":"
             + "{  \"label\": \"Infections\","
             + "  \"data\": [[1988, 0], [1989, 0], [1990, 10], [1991, 35], [1992, 28]] "
             + "}"
             + "}";
        mAppView.loadUrl("javascript:GotGraph('"+json+"');");
```

Javascript side (FLOT) (allows multiple lines

```
function GotGraph(data) {

    var datasets = JSON.parse(data);

    // hard-code color indices to prevent them from shifting as
    // countries are turned on/off
    var i = 0;
    $.each(datasets, function(key, val) {
        val.color = i;
        ++i;
    });

    // insert checkboxes 
    var choiceContainer = $("#choices");
    $.each(datasets, function(key, val) {
        choiceContainer.append('<br/><input type="checkbox" name="' + key +
                               '" checked="checked" id="id' + key + '">' +
                               '<label for="id' + key + '">'
                                + val.label + '</label>');
    });
    choiceContainer.find("input").click(plotAccordingToChoices);


    // 
    function plotAccordingToChoices() {
        var data = [];

        choiceContainer.find("input:checked").each(function () {
            var key = $(this).attr("name");
            if (key && datasets[key])
                data.push(datasets[key]);
        });

        if (data.length > 0)
            $.plot($("#placeholder"), data, {
                yaxis: { min: 0 },
                xaxis: { tickDecimals: 0 }
            });
    }

    plotAccordingToChoices();

}
```

Thanks to

http://rapidandroid.org/wiki/Graphing

http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-charts-the-html5-and-javascript-way/

and @achie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is what you have shown is not a valid JSON object.

Did you try validating the JSON object that you are trying to use? I validated it on http://www.jsonlint.com/ and http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/.

They will show you the errors in your JSON object.

If you look at the docs in http://json.org/ they show you that every string needs to be in quotes ex "string". your example does not follow that. You also have a trailing comma after your last object.

Here is how your actual JSON might look

```
{
    "Symptoms": {
        "label": "Symptoms",
        "data": [[1988, 10], [1989, 20], [1990, 10], [1991, 30], [1992, 40]]
    },        
    "Reactions": {
        "label": "Reactions",
                    "data": [[1988, 0], [1989, 0], [1990, 10], [1991, 30], [1992, 40]]

    },
    "Injections": {
        "label": "Injections",
                    "data": [[1988, 0], [1989, 0], [1990, 0], [1991, 30], [1992, 40]]

    }

}
```

Now if you want to parse or create json objects and arrays in android, [there are four convenient classes which are very useful.](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html)

You can use those to do whatever manipulations you want to do on actual JSON objects. They will always follow JSON guidelines.

To get label in your example you have to use JSONObject.getString("label") on your json Object.

Here is [another example.](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/)

Comment: thanks after almost six hours I finally got what I wanted :) Never thought of validating it. Because it worked :) I'll post my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into `Gson`.  It has its own serializers and deserializers [Gson User Guide](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserializ)